# How to pass the JSON array in this

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jData is actually a JSON array but when I try to pass it it gives me an error.

This below works:

```
$test.pass = {
    lines:{ID:'ID', Date:'Date'},
    data:{}
};
```

but when I want to pass a JSON array that I am getting back from an ajax I get an error.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function(data){ 
       $test.pass = {
          lines:{ID:'ID', Date:'Date'},
          data:data
       };   
    }                 
});
```

it gives me an error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data'  undefined

Comment: Nowhere in your code do I see `rows`, show the part of the code that applies to the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $test a 'global' variable? If you put a breakpoint on the first line in the success function, what is the value of data?